# Python. Напишите функцию которая создаёт словарь из двух списков разной длины

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Есть два списка разной длины. В первом содержатся ключи, а во втором — значения. Напишите функцию `make_dict`, которая создаёт из этих ключей и значений словарь. Если ключу не хватило значения, в словаре должно быть значение **None**. *Функция должна игнорировать значения, которым не хватило ключей и должна возвращать словарь без значения **None**.*

Я попытался написать код:

```
k = ["key_1", "key_2", "key_3", "key_4", "key_5"]
v = ["val_1", "val_2", "val_3"]

make_dict = {}
x = 0

while x < len(k):
    try:
        make_dict[k[x]] = v[x]
        x = x + 1
    except:
        make_dict[k[x]] = "None"
    x = x + 1

print(make_dict)
```

Она возвращает созданный словарь.

Но у меня не получается из этого создать функцию.
А также не пойму как сделать "*Значения, которым не хватило ключей, нужно игнорировать.*"

Пока что, ответ от пользователя Алексей Р является наиболее актуальным.
Вариант от Kirill Kondratenko у меня выдаёт ошибку.
Но всё же хотелось бы увидеть решения которые будут полностью отвечать условиям задачи. А именно - Сама функция (**def**) *должна игнорировать значения, которым не хватило ключей и должна возвращать словарь без значения **None**.*

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Так для отсутствующих ключей должно быть _строковое_ значение `"None"`, или всё-таки `None` как эквивалент `null` (отсутствие значения)?  И какой смысл тогда в условии _функция должна возвращать словарь без значения **None**_?

Answer (score 4):

**Решение с zip_longest**

```
from itertools import zip_longest

k = ["key_1", "key_2", "key_3", "key_4", "key_5"]
v = ["val_1", "val_2", "val_3"]


def make_dict(keys: list, values: list) -> dict:
    return {k: v for k, v in zip_longest(keys, values) if k}


print(make_dict(k, v))
print(make_dict(k[:2], v))  # передаем часть списка ключей
```

```
{'key_1': 'val_1', 'key_2': 'val_2', 'key_3': 'val_3', 'key_4': None, 'key_5': None}
{'key_1': 'val_1', 'key_2': 'val_2'}
```

**Решение с zip**

```
k = ["key_1", "key_2", "key_3", "key_4", "key_5"]
v = ["val_1", "val_2", "val_3"]


def make_dict(keys: list, values: list) -> dict:
    return {k: v for k, v in (zip(keys, values + [None] * (len(keys) - len(values))))}  # или dict(zip(keys, values + [None] * (len(keys) - len(values))))


print(make_dict(k, v))
print(make_dict(k[:2], v))  # передаем часть списка ключей
```

**Решение без zip**

```
k = ["key_1", "key_2", "key_3", "key_4", "key_5"]
v = ["val_1", "val_2", "val_3"]


def make_dict(keys: list, values: list) -> dict:
    return {k: values[i] if i < len(values) else None for i, k in enumerate(keys)}


print(make_dict(k, v))
print(make_dict(k[:2], v))  # передаем часть списка ключей
```

**Решение с применением срезов**
Если список значений уже исчерпан, а ключи еще есть, то выражение `values[i:i + 1] or None` возвращает None как значение.

```
k = ["key_1", "key_2", "key_3", "key_4", "key_5"]
v = ["val_1", "val_2", "val_3"]


def make_dict(keys: list, values: list) -> dict:
    return {k: values[i:i + 1] or None for i, k in enumerate(keys)}


print(make_dict(k, v))
print(make_dict(k[:2], v))  # передаем часть списка ключей
```

Comment: А возможно ли как-то изменить def таким образом, чтобы print(make_dict(k, v)) сразу игнорировал все значения, которым не хватило ключей?

Comment: Ну да, можно перебирать или обрезать списки по кол-ву ключей

Comment: "Ну да, можно перебирать или обрезать списки по кол-ву ключей" - А как сделать перебор?

Comment: Организовать цикл в той или иной форме. Например, `for` или списковое включение или словарное включение

Comment: @АлексейР поздравляю с достижением 10k!

Answer (score 1):

```
def make_dict(test_keys, test_values):
    for i in range(0, len(test_keys) - len(test_values)):
        test_values.append(None)
    res = {}
    for key in test_keys:
        for value in test_values:
            res[key] = value
            test_values.remove(value)
            break
    return res
```

Пример 1:

```
test_keys = ["alfa", "beta", "gamma"]
test_values = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
make_dict(test_keys, test_values)

{'alfa': 1, 'beta': 4, 'gamma': 5}
```

Пример 2:

```
test_keys = ["alfa", "beta", "gamma"]
test_values = [1, 4]
make_dict(test_keys, test_values)

{'alfa': 1, 'beta': 4, 'gamma': None}
```

Comment: Во-первых, отформатируйте нормально ответ. Во-вторых, здесь все-таки русский сайт, пишите по-русски, а не по-английски.

Comment: Это уже ответ, а не вопрос. А со словом exmaple вряд ли у кого-то возникнут проблемы)

Comment: Да, я перепутал, отформатируйте, пожалуйста, код в ответе.

Comment: И все равно часть кода торчит. Код нужно выделять строчками ``` сверху и снизу.

Comment: @Глеб так лучше?

Comment: V а s i l i y Z a y c e v, если ответ подходит отметьте галочкой, пожалуйста

Comment: @Глеб это русскоязычный раздел сайта. Сайт, конечно же, не русский, а очень даже американский.

Comment: Я попытался запустить ваш код и у меня выдало : 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
make_dict(test_keys, test_values)
NameError: name 'make_dict' is not defined.

Возможно я что-то не так делаю.
Не могли бы вы показать полностью сформированный код, чтобы его можно было запустить для проверки вашего Пример 1:.

Comment: Запустите код на чистом проекте, сначала прогоните функцию в первом блоке, потом пример из любого блока
Для прогона примеров не копируйте последнюю строку - это пример готового вывода

Comment: Пример готового вывода надо было закомментировать и подписать, чтобы понятно было. "Проект" нужно делать не всем, а только тем, кто работает в pycharm. Что значит "прогоните функцию"? Нужно сделать не несколько обрывков, а один целый код, который можно взять, скопировать и запустить. Если вы "прогоните" функцию (я так понимаю, что вы под этим подразумеваете запуск функции без ничего), то она молча прочитается и все на этом.

Comment: Буду иметь ввиду, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

можно еще так:

```
def make_dict(k, v):
    d = dict.fromkeys(k)
    ik = iter(k)
    iv = iter(v)
    for i in range(min(len(k), len(v))):
        d[next(ik)] = next(iv)
    return d
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот вариант с zip и со срезами. Не однострочник, но зато есть проверка на хешируемость ключа и убираются дубли из списка ключей.

```
from typing import Optional

def make_dict(keys_list: list, values_list: list) -> Optional[dict]:
    try:
        keys_set_list = list(dict.fromkeys(keys_list))
        result = dict(zip(keys_set_list, values_list))
        {result.setdefault(x) for x in keys_set_list[len(values_list):]}
        return result
    except TypeError as e:
        print(e)
```

Можно попробовать вот на таких данных:

```
k = ["key_1", "key_2", "key_3", "key_4", "key_5", "key_3", "key_1"]
v = ["val_1", "val_2", "val_3"]
print(make_dict(k, v))


k = ["key_1", [1, 2], "key_3"]
v = ["val_1", "val_2", "val_3"]
print(make_dict(k, v))
```